# Can i create a new CultureInfo from a two-character language code?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I need to format a number, based on a culture, but all I have is the `Accept-Language` from the HTTP request, which is a two-letter code like `fr` (for French)

Is this enough to create a CultureInfo that can handle numbers?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The following code:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("fr");
Console.WriteLine(13.45.ToString(ci));
```

outputs "13,45" which is using the french decimal separator in the number.

The [CultureInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> A neutral culture is specified by only the two-letter lowercase language code. For example, fr specifies the neutral culture for French, and de specifies the neutral culture for German.

Comment: Note that `ci.CultureTypes` will have the flag `NeutralCultures` in that case. Equivalently, [`ci.IsNeutralCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tkwe67b.aspx) gives `true`. That is not really recommended. It is better to use something like `new CultureInfo("fr-CA")` where you give both a language and a country, corresponding to flag `SpecificCultures`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Would you recommend just picking an arbitrary country rather than doing the above then? What are the drawbacks of it being a NeutralCulture compared to choosing a country for it?

Comment: `var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr")` picks a specific culture for you. In this example it picks `"fr-FR"`, that is _French (France)_. I am no expert here, though.

Answer (score 8):

This is a comment to illustrate the difference between [neutral cultures and specific cultures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx):

```
var language = "fr";

var c1 = new CultureInfo(language);
Console.WriteLine(c1.EnglishName);              // "French"
Console.WriteLine(c1.IsNeutralCulture);         // "True"
Console.WriteLine((3.14m).ToString("C", c1));   // "3,14 €"

var c2 = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
Console.WriteLine(c2.EnglishName);              // "French (France)"
Console.WriteLine(c2.IsNeutralCulture);         // "False"
Console.WriteLine((3.14m).ToString("C", c2));   // "3,14 €"

var languageAndCountry = "fr-CA";

var c3 = new CultureInfo(languageAndCountry);
Console.WriteLine(c3.EnglishName);              // "French (Canada)"
Console.WriteLine(c3.IsNeutralCulture);         // "False"
Console.WriteLine((3.14m).ToString("C", c3));   // "3,14 $"
```

In conclusion, if you have only the language, you cannot get everything. You can either get a neutral culture, or a "canonical" specific culture where some "typical" country is picked.

When you have both language and country, as in `"fr-CA"`, things behave better.

---

On my system, the following specific cultures with `"fr"` exist:

> fr-029, fr-BE, fr-BF, fr-BI, fr-BJ, fr-BL, fr-CA, fr-CD, fr-CF, fr-CG, fr-CH, fr-CI, fr-CM, fr-DJ, fr-DZ, fr-FR, fr-GA, fr-GF, fr-GN, fr-GP, fr-GQ, fr-HT, fr-KM, fr-LU, fr-MA, fr-MC, fr-MF, fr-MG, fr-ML, fr-MQ, fr-MR, fr-MU, fr-NC, fr-NE, fr-PF, fr-PM, fr-RE, fr-RW, fr-SC, fr-SN, fr-SY, fr-TD, fr-TG, fr-TN, fr-VU, fr-WF, fr-YT

(found with `string.Join(", ", CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Where(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "fr"))`)